# NLTK PunktSentenceTokenizer ellipsis splitting

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, tokenize

I'm working with NLTK [PunktSentenceTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.punkt.PunktSentenceTokenizer) and I'm facing a situation where the a text containing multiple sentences separated by the [ellipsis character (...)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). Here is the example I'm working on:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
>>> pst = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
>>> pst.sentences_from_text("Horrible customer service... Cashier was rude... Drive thru took hours... The tables were not clean...")
['Horrible customer service... Cashier was rude... Drive thru took hours... The tables were not clean...']
```

As you can see, the sentences are not separated. Is there a way to make it work as I could expect it (that is, returning a list with four items)?

**Additional information**: I've tried to use the `debug_decisions` function to try to understand why such decision was made. I got the following result:

```
>>> g = pst.debug_decisions("Horrible customer service... Cashier was rude... Drive thru took hours... The tables were not clean...")

>>> [x for x in g]
[{'break_decision': None,
  'collocation': False,
  'period_index': 27,
  'reason': 'default decision',
  'text': 'service... Cashier',
  'type1': '...',
  'type1_in_abbrs': False,
  'type1_is_initial': False,
  'type2': 'cashier',
  'type2_is_sent_starter': False,
  'type2_ortho_contexts': set(),
  'type2_ortho_heuristic': 'unknown'},
 {'break_decision': None,
  'collocation': False,
  'period_index': 47,
  'reason': 'default decision',
  'text': 'rude... Drive',
  'type1': '...',
  'type1_in_abbrs': False,
  'type1_is_initial': False,
  'type2': 'drive',
  'type2_is_sent_starter': False,
  'type2_ortho_contexts': set(),
  'type2_ortho_heuristic': 'unknown'},
 {'break_decision': None,
  'collocation': False,
  'period_index': 72,
  'reason': 'default decision',
  'text': 'hours... The',
  'type1': '...',
  'type1_in_abbrs': False,
  'type1_is_initial': False,
  'type2': 'the',
  'type2_is_sent_starter': False,
  'type2_ortho_contexts': set(),
  'type2_ortho_heuristic': 'unknown'}]
```

I was unfortunately not able to understand the meaning of these dict, although it seems that the tokenizer did actually detect the ellipsis but for some reason took the decision to *not* split the sentence by these symbols. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use [the split function?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
 `str.split('...')`

EDIT: I got this to work by training the function with the reuters corpus, i guess you could train it using yours:

```
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import reuters
pst = PunktSentenceTokenizer()
pst.train(reuters.raw())
text = "Batts did not take questions or give details of the report's findings... He did say that the city's police department would continue to work on the case under the direction of the prosecutor's office. Gray was injured around the time he was arrested by Baltimore police and put in a police van on 12 April."
print(pst.sentences_from_text(text))
```

resulted in:

```
>>> ["Batts did not take questions or give details of the report's findings...", "He did say that the city's police department would continue to work on the case under the direction of the prosecutor's office.", 'Gray was injured around the time he was arrested by Baltimore police and put in a police van on 12 April.']
```

Comment: I don't think `'...'` is used only at the end of a sentence. You can use it between symbols do describe a continuation (e.g.: "The value will be in range 1...5") or to represent an omission when quoting (see: http://www.writeexpress.com/ellipses.html). I think the whole point of using a trained classifier to tokenize the sentences is to make the difference between all the possible uses of punctuation symbols.

Comment: Okay, excuse my hasty answer, that's a very good point. I read some about the class and it seems like PunktSentenceTokenizer is an untrained method that you need to train with some context (and I assume that you aren't doing that). However there is another similar class that is already trained called nltk.tokenize.punkt. The documentation shows how to use it [link](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)

Comment: No worries, thank you for trying to help. I checked the link and attempted to use `nltk.tokenize.punkt` as in the example (training on `nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")`). I got the following result from my example: `['Horrible customer service... Cashier was rude... Drive thru took hours...', 'The tables were not clean...']`. It still could not separate the three first sentences. If I want to train the tokenizer on my own data to fit my own needs, how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: So i experimented a little bit since this concerns the work that I'm currently working on. See edit, it works for me now.

Comment: The `train` method here is performing an unsupervised learning, which is not reliable enough (given the training time) for my needs. When doing the same on my example, only the last sentence get split from the three other ones. Do you (or anyone else) know if there is a way to train some sentence tokenizer with some kind of supervised learning so that I can tune it with more accuracy?
Maybe training it with a domain specific corpus would yield more accurate result though.

Comment: @Romain, the punkt tokenizer _is_ an unsupervised algorithm -- the model that comes with the nltk was trained the same way. If that's not good enough for your purposes, you could always pre- or post-process your corpus with a rule-based (regexp?) tokenizer. Your particular problem case seems easy enough to handle (check for what follows the ellipsis).